# MD5 collision for known input

Tags: md5, collision

Is it possible to create a MD5 collision based on a known input value?

So for example I have input string `abc` with MD5 `900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72`.
Now I want to add bytes to string `def` to get the same MD5 `900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72`.

(I know this is possible by bruteforcing and waiting a long time; I want to know if there is a more efficient way in doing this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unitl now no algorithm has been discovered that allows you to find a matching input that will generate a given md5 hash.

What has been proven is that you can create md5 collisions quite easily, for example with what is known as *chosen-prefix-collision*: you can create two files yielding the same md5 hash by appending different data to a specified file. If you want to know more or get the program to try it, look [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/).

Comment: I found these tools creating two different files within 2 seconds with the same MD5 but it's not what I was looking for.
But thanks for the answer.